# Why PyAutoGui commands not working in cmd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, automation, pyautogui

I wrote the code to open the cmd and then change its title. It is working till opening the cmd but it is not writing anything there.

```
import pyautogui as pg

pg.hotkey('win','r')
pg.write('cmd')
pg.press('enter')
pg.write('title title changed')
pg.press('enter')
```

Comment: You can open a Command Prompt window with one or more commands as arguments, by using either its `/C`, or `/K` option, instead of trying to chain commands like that. For instance `C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /K "Title Title Changed"` would open a Command Prompt window, run the command `Title Title Changed`, and keep the window open for further use as needed.

Comment: @Compo How could I run more than one command

Comment: You can chain commands together using an ampersand; for example: `… /K "Title Title Changed & Pause & Title Title Different & Pause"`.

Comment: @Compo And in case I want to continue executing commands in an open cmd using automation.